# Script does not backup the job

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, backup

I have the script below to generate backup of all the bases of the server, manually executing it works, but when I run the JOB it executes but does not do what it has to do ..
I need to back up to a storage on the same network.
Everything works perfectly manually but not on the job

```
--================================================================================================================================================================
--CRIA MAPEAMENTO E LIMPA BACKUP ANTERIOR
--================================================================================================================================================================
exec xp_cmdshell 'net use y: /delete'
go
exec xp_cmdshell 'if not exist y:\ net use y: CAMINHO /user:usuario senha'
go
--================================================================================================================================================================
--cria tabela do dia
--================================================================================================================================================================
declare @p_dia varchar(100),@cmd varchar(100)
set @p_dia = replace(convert(varchar(7),getdate(),121),'-','\') + '\' + convert(varchar(10),getdate(),112) + '\' +
reverse(substring(reverse(cast(CONNECTIONPROPERTY('local_net_address') as varchar(100))),1,charindex('.',
reverse(cast(CONNECTIONPROPERTY('local_net_address') as varchar(100))))-1))

select @p_dia

set @cmd = 'exec xp_create_subdir ''Y:\' + @p_dia + ''''
exec(@cmd)

set @cmd = 'exec xp_cmdshell ''del /s/q  Y:\' + @p_dia + '\*.*'''
exec(@cmd)



--================================================================================================================================================================
--BASES NAO HISTORICO - BACKUP FULL DIARIO
--================================================================================================================================================================
IF OBJECT_ID('MASTER.DBO.TBL_BASES_BACKUP') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE TBL_BASES_BACKUP

select 
    name,
    row_number() over(order by (select null)) as contador
INTO TBL_BASES_BACKUP
from sys.databases
where name not like '%hist%'
and name not in('tempdb')


DECLARE @I INT = 0 ,
        @CMD2 VARCHAR(MAX)  ='',
        @base varchar(100) = '',
        @data_Formatada varchar(10) = replace(convert(varchar(10),getdate(),103),'/','_')
while @i <= (select max(contador) from TBL_BASES_BACKUP)
begin 
set @base = (select name from TBL_BASES_BACKUP where contador = @i)
set @CMD2 = '
BACKUP DATABASE ' + quotename(@base) + ' TO  DISK = ''Y:\'+@p_dia+'\'+@base+'_backup_'+@data_Formatada+'_230032_0713493.bak'' 
WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'''+@base+'-Completo Banco de Dados Backup'', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, COMPRESSION,  STATS = 10
'
exec(@cmd2)
set @i = @i + 1
end
```

Comment: I must advise you switch to [Ola's scripts](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html) which are well documented, open source, has won multiple awards, etc. It'll do more than you'll ever need. Aside from that, check the error logs. I'm betting the credentials that runs agent doesn't have permission to the directories or something.

Comment: Can you provide some details on the problem? You said it "does not do what it has to do". What does that mean? What happens? I second the recommendation to use Ola's scripts.

Comment: The job succeeds in history but the backup file is not generated in the specified path. Apparently it goes through the entire script and does not perform the task

Comment: If you print "@cmd2" and try to execute it manually. Does it work?

Comment: the reverse property (substring (reverse (cast (CONNECTIONPROPERTY ('local_net_address') to varchar (100)), 1, charindex ('.',
reverse (cast (CONNECTIONPROPERTY ('local_net_address') as varchar (100)))) - 1)) was returning null when it was placed in the job. I got it sorted out.